# jQuery to parse this JSON response how?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is my code:

```
<?php

$steamids = '76561197960435530';
$APIKEY = MYAPPKEY;

$steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
$json_object= file_get_contents($steamAPI);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_object;

?>
```

I get everything what I need when I go to this `info.php` file. 
But how should I jQuery parse this JSON response ? I would like to do something like this:

```
function steamFunction(data){
    $("#userinfo").html('<img src="' +data.response.players.avatar +'">');
}
```

Is it possible somehow ?

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){
     $("#userinfo").html(json.response.players.avatar);
});
});
```

I'm not getting any errors but the image wont appearing. Also when I alert this I get `undefined`

Comment: And how are you calling `info.php`? With an ajax call?

Comment: @adeneo No. I just go to localhost:8888/info.php and get all the info about account.

Comment: So how would jQuery parse that?  It's not even an html page.  It's just the response from php...

Comment: How should I make it to work ?

Comment: presumably you're doing an ajax request to get this json? `$.getJSON('yoururl.php', function(data) { ...do stuff here...});`

Comment: @MarcB I'll try this

Comment: First, echo the PHP variable into a JS variable. Second, parse the JS variable.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can u show me the code please ?

Comment: I'm getting this GET http://localhost:8888/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @adeneo I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try instead this code:-

```
    $.getJSON( "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=76561197960435530&key=52A66B13219F645834149F1A1180770A&format=json", function( json ) {
    console.log (json.response.players[0].avatar);


});
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try $.parseJSON ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){
        json = $.parseJSON(json);
        $("#userinfo").html(json.response.players.avatar);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Comment: You should try to see what is the response you receive. You can use `console.log(json);` before and after the `json = $.parseJSON(json);` Maybe the input of the function is not what you expect ;)